# Rails 4 Static Public index.html

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, static, ruby-on-rails-4, indexing

Sorry about the simple question, but I can't find the proper fix anywhere.

I used to have a Rails 3.x app running with a simple landing page on public/index.html. Of course, when I updated to Rails 4, my index page is no longer showing. Is there any way to get that feature back?

I know I can create a welcome#index controller/route and render the index.html as a response.
But that goes to a different folder, without all the image and css assets that were on public, rendering the former static page.

Any tips?

Comment: you can set your root path in the routes file to point to the welcome#index

Comment: hey. did you solve it? I found in http://blog.benmorgan.io/post/77446075979/setting-up-an-angularjs-app-with-a-rails-api to use get '/', to: redirect('/') but in production (heroku) it says something about a loop redirecting

Comment: Did you solve it? *2.

Comment: @fabricioflores Turns out rails actually just renders the index file in public if you have one. GET / will load index.html if available.

Comment: Im experiencing the same.
My Plesk webserver sets httpdocs/myrailsapp/public as the website root
and therefore it just loads the public/index.html even with 
config/routes.rb: root 'pages#index'

I haven't found any solution to this and tech support from the host company isn't very helpful either. Any idea?

(Ruby 2.6.3, Rails 6, Phusion Passenger, Apache, Nginx)

Answer (score 22):

You need to use a controller, but can simply point it to your existing file.

e.g. in routes.rb

```
root :to => 'welcome#index'
```

And then in the Welcome controller:

```
def index
  render :file => 'public/index.html'
end
```

Alternatively, you could set up Apache to serve that file itself. Seems easier to let Rails do it though!

Comment: Yeah, I did that render :file index.html

The problem is that all the assets files are not loaded because they are also on the /public folder.

I'd like a way to render the index.html file in place (public folder) the way Rails 3 did before.

Comment: I love when an upgrade kills my productivity :)

Answer (score 7):

Placing a public/index.html and removing the root directive from config/routes.rb works for me.

```
$ rails --version
$ Rails 4.2.0
```

Comment: Worked for me too on Rails 4.2.0

Comment: @PeterSankauskas Works for me in Rails5

Answer (score 0):

A problem with just adding `public/index.html` is that the index page may not render unless a root path of `/` is present.

For example, if the app is hosted in a sub-uri, 'http://example.com/my-app/' will hit `index.html`, but 'http://example.com/my-app' (no trailing `/`) may not. This could probably be fixed in the configuration of the web server, but if you don't have control of that, you can fix this in routes with:

```
root to: redirect('index.html')
```